# Repeat items in Appendix in Alphabetical order

Tags: macros, sorting

I would like to create a command (or environment) that takes a name, prints the contents, and repeats the contents in the appendix, ordered alphabetically by the name.

For example:

```
\monkeyInfo{tamarin}{
Tamarins are awesome monkeys.\\
%Maybe more text...
%Maybe a figure...
%etcetc
}

\monkeyInfo{capuchin}{
There was a capuchin monkey on Friends.\\
%more here...
%more...
}
```

Then, later, in an appendix, something like this:

```
\chapter{Alphabetical Monkeys}

\includeMonkeyInfos
```

In the output, in the normal text, the Tamarin entry should come before the Capuchin.  In the appendix, they should be repeated, but in alphabetical order, so the Capuchin entry will come before the Tamarin.

What is the correct way to create the macro/environment for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using [`datatool`](//ctan.org/pkg/datatool) to manage the data since it can also be used to sort the database and print everything the way you want. Here's a quick run through what it could look like:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLnewdb{monkey}

\newcommand{\monkeyInfo}[2]{%
  \par\noindent
  #1:\space\ignorespaces #2% Set the info associated with this particular monkey
  \DTLnewrow{monkey}% Add a new row to the monkey database
  \DTLnewdbentry{monkey}{name}{#1}% Insert monkey name
  \DTLnewdbentry{monkey}{description}{#2}% Insert the monkey description
}

\newcommand{\includeMonkeyInfos}{%
  \dtlsort{name=ascending}{monkey}{\dtlcompare}% Sort database by name
  \DTLforeach{monkey}{%
    % Define variables for each key
    \MonkeyName=name,
    \MonkeyDescription=description%
  }{%
    % How each item in the database should be set
    \par\addvspace{.25\baselineskip}
    \noindent\textbf{\MonkeyName}: \MonkeyDescription
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Monkeys}

\monkeyInfo{tamarin}{%
Tamarins are awesome monkeys.\\
%Maybe more text...
%Maybe a figure...
%etcetc
}

\monkeyInfo{capuchin}{%
There was a capuchin monkey on Friends.\\
%more here...
%more...
}

\appendix

\section{Appendix}

\includeMonkeyInfos

\end{document}
```

Note that `datatool` can't handle paragraphs (blank lines) in the definitions it stores. If you want to do that, you need to use `\DTLpar`. It would be better if you know the structure of content to be supplied that you define an accommodating input format. That would allow you to format the content in a consistent manner as well. But other than that, basic uses of content works as-is.

Comment: Can you use tikz inside of the DTLnewdbentries?

Comment: @Kyle: You should be able to, as long as none of the category codes have changed. I haven't tried though.

Comment: I am able to use tikz inside of this, and tcolorbox.  Excellent!